# Laravel vue axios not returning response.data

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

This is my first time using laravel Vue and axios. I am trying to add a Subscribe button to my users channel. It is not returning the subscribers response in axios?. Do i have the response.data wrong or the out put in the template or both? any help would be good. I can provide more code if needed. thanks

AppSubscribeButton.vue

```
    <template>
    <div v-if="subscribers !== null">
        {{ subscribers }} Subscribe &nbsp;
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" type="button" v-if="canSubscribe">{{ userSubscribed ? 'Unsubscribe' : 'Subscribe' }}</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import pluralize from 'pluralize'

export default {
        data () {
            return {
                subscribers: null,
                userSubscribed: false,
                canSubscribe: false
            }
        },
         props: {
            channelSlug: null
        },
        methods: {
            getSubscriptionStatus () {
                   axios.get('/subscription/' + this.channelSlug).then((response) => {
                    this.subscribers = response.data.count;
                    this.userSubscribed = response.data.user_subscribed;
                    this.canSubscribe = response.data.can_subscribe;
                 })
                },
            pluralize    
            },
        mounted () {
            this.getSubscriptionStatus();
        }

    }
</script>
```

my web.php

```
<?php

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/channel/{channel}', 'ChannelController@show');

Route::get('/subscription/{channel}', 'ChannelSubscriptionController@show');

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);


Route::group(['middleware' => ['verified']], function() {


Route::group(['prefix' => 'account', 'middleware' => ['auth'], 'as' => 'account.'], function () {

    /**
     * Account
     */
    Route::get('/', 'Account\AccountController@index')->name('index');

    /**
    * Profile
    */
    Route::get('profile', 'Account\ProfileController@index')->name('profile');
    Route::post('profile', 'Account\ProfileController@store')->name('profile.store');

    /**
    * Password
    */
    Route::get('password', 'Account\PasswordController@index')->name('password');
    Route::post('password', 'Account\PasswordController@store')->name('password.store');
});


    /**
    * Dashboard
    */
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');



    /**
    * Teams
    */
    Route::resource('teams', 'Teams\TeamController');

    Route::get('teams/{team}/delete', 'Teams\TeamController@delete')
        ->name('teams.delete');

    Route::get('teams/{team}/users/{user}/delete', 'Teams\TeamUserController@delete')
        ->name('teams.users.delete');   

    Route::resource('teams/{team}/users', 'Teams\TeamUserController')->names([
        'index' => 'teams.users.index',
        'store' => 'teams.users.store',
        'destroy' => 'teams.users.destroy',
    ]);

    Route::get('teams/{team}/users/{user}/roles', 'Teams\TeamUserRoleController@edit')
        ->name('teams.users.roles.edit');

    Route::patch('teams/{team}/users/{user}/roles', 'Teams\TeamUserRoleController@update')
        ->name('teams.users.roles.update');

    /**
    * Channels
    */  
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
        Route::get('/channel/{channel}/edit', 'ChannelSettingsController@edit');
        Route::put('/channel/{channel}/edit', 'ChannelSettingsController@update');
        Route::get('/createchannel', 'ChannelCreateController@index')->name('createchannel');
        Route::put('/createchannel', 'ChannelCreateController@store')->name('createchannel.store');
        Route::get('/channel/{channel}/delete', 'ChannelSettingsController@index');
        Route::delete('/channel/{channel}/delete', 'ChannelSettingsController@destroy')->name('createchannel.destroy');
    });

});
```

if i console.log(subscribers) I get this error

```
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: subscribers is not defined"

found in

---> <SubscribeButton> at resources/js/components/AppSubscribeButton.vue
       <Root> app.js:38444:15
    warn http://teams.com:8000/js/app.js:38444
    logError http://teams.com:8000/js/app.js:39703
    globalHandleError http://teams.com:8000/js/app.js:39698
    handleError http://teams.com:8000/js/app.js:39658
    invokeWithErrorHandling http://teams.com:8000/js/app.js:39681
    callHook http://teams.com:8000/js/app.js:42024
    insert http://teams.com:8000/js/app.js:40956
    invokeInsertHook http://teams.com:8000/js/app.js:44145
    patch http://teams.com:8000/js/app.js:44362
    _update http://teams.com:8000/js/app.js:41750
    updateComponent http://teams.com:8000/js/app.js:41871
    get http://teams.com:8000/js/app.js:42282
    Watcher http://teams.com:8000/js/app.js:42271
    mountComponent http://teams.com:8000/js/app.js:41878
    $mount http://teams.com:8000/js/app.js:46848
    $mount http://teams.com:8000/js/app.js:49733
    _init http://teams.com:8000/js/app.js:42816
    Vue http://teams.com:8000/js/app.js:42882
    js http://teams.com:8000/js/app.js:49869
    __webpack_require__ http://teams.com:8000/js/app.js:20
    0 http://teams.com:8000/js/app.js:50007
    __webpack_require__ http://teams.com:8000/js/app.js:20
    <anonymous> http://teams.com:8000/js/app.js:84
    <anonymous> http://teams.com:8000/js/app.js:87
```

Comment: Are you seeing the request and response in the browser dev tools? Are you receiving an error that your system is just swallowing, as you don't appear to have an error handler on your request.

Comment: Try to see the error message in your chrome's element. What's that response code and message?

Comment: try `console.log(this.subscribers)` if it returns any data

Comment: wow thank you for a quick reply...when i do console.log i do not see any errors in the dev console tools :(

 mounted () {
            this.getSubscriptionStatus();
           console.log(this.subscribers)
        }

If I change the button to this i can see the subscribe and the button ...looks like {{ subscribers }} is not working to get the count ?

<div v-if="subscribers !== null">
        subscribers &nbsp; 
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button">Subscribe</button>
    </div>

Comment: It is my first time using axios so i do not know if this is right ?

    methods: {
               getSubscriptionStatus () {
                         axios.get('/subscription/' + this.channelSlug).then((response) =>  {
                       this.subscribers = response.data.count;
                       this.userSubscribed = response.data.user_subscribed;
                       this.canSubscribe = response.data.can_subscribe;
                    })
                   },

Comment: can you please add your web.php and controller codes as well?
ALso add the error code, so we can easily understand it!

Comment: I have added my web.php ...if I console.log(subscribers) I get this error ?

[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: subscribers is not defined"

Comment: You should use this.$data.subscribers inside the function. I hope it will work.

Comment: just tried this.$data.subscribers and didn't work :( ...if I changed this.$data.subscribers = response.data.count; to this.$data.subscribers = response.data; it returns a out put { "data": { "count": 0, "user_subscribed": false, "can_subscribe": true } } ....am i not getting the a count from axios response ?